# Most Effective Way to Split Lucene QueryString by Whitespace

Tags: java, lucene

When splitting a search query by whitespace so that when searching for a name for example the term "John Doe" will match results "John", "Doe", or "John Doe" as opposed to only the entire query in its entirety. This is how I am doing it now:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
String[] terms = queryString.split(" ");
for(String term : terms) {
    booleanQuery.add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("firstName", term)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    booleanQuery.add(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("lastName", term)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
```

To me this approach seams a little messy. Is there is a better way?

Comment: why don't you use QueryParser?

Comment: yeah use QueryParser and WhiteSpaceAnalyzer (if you want to split only on whitespaces)

Comment: I used a booleanquery with a fuzzy because I wanted to be able to match partial words such as Jon would pull up John etc. Can QueryParser and WhiteSpaceAnalyzer achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your query parser is wrong if you are not using a trivial analyzer. [You should analyze query terms the same way they were analyzed at indexing time](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Why_is_it_important_to_use_the_same_analyzer_type_during_indexing_and_search.3F).

According to what you are trying to do, you should probably split your query string with your analyzer. It is not compulsory, but if you don't (for example you could split on whitespaces and then analyze every word independently), you will need to solve some (nontrivial) problems:

- what to do when the analysis of a word yields several terms (can happen with compound names)?
- what to do when the word is a stop word (does not yield any token)?